# How to integrate my webapplication in client website dashboard with Single sign?

Tags: single-sign-on

My site was .Net webapp.It was linked some where in client dashboard.
But client website have duo idp 2 factor authentication.
Whenever client logins to his website and enter his valid logins and if he is authenticated as a valid user by **duo idp** then he will able to login his dashboard.
After succesfully login to dashboard(his app) if the client is trying to access my integratrd application link then he can able access my .Net app without asking username and password.

My .Net app don't have any saml settings.
please help me on this and how many ways we can do this single sign on.